# specify a delay in camera upload

Tags: dropbox

Is there a way to specify a delay before my Dropbox app uploads photos into my Dropbox account.  I normally take a lot of photos, and delete many of it.  Dropbox app puts it onto my space before that. How do I specify a delay before it copies? Right now, I have to go to Dropbox and delete them again

Answer (score 0):

The only way I think of would be to disable wifi and data while you take your photos and delete those you want to... Or enable the upload only on wifi, if you're not connected on wifi when you take your photos.